# How do I rename the index.html file in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to have a different filename then index.html in the /dist folder when I do `ember build`. Something like main.html would be great.

Comment: How would you rename any other file?

Comment: I am sorry I think my question is not very clear. I will rewrite it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Brocfile.js

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    outputPaths: {
        app: {
            html: 'main.html'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: do not rename index.html to main.html in your "app" folder

Comment: @GabeRainbow can you expand on that?